# Point only homepage to GitHub pages and use GCP web server for everything else

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns, github-pages

I have an Apache Web Server running on a GCP compute instance. Currently, I have a custom domain pointing to GitHub pages using CNAMEs and A Records. How can I continue with that functionality while also redirecting any subfolders to my web server?

Desired behaviour:

```
example.com --> xyz.github.io [currently working]
www.example.com --> xyz.github.io [currently working]

example.com/folder/item --> File on GCP webserver
www.example.com/folder/item --> File on GCP webserver
```

I think it might be possible with `.htaccess` redirects but I believe that would cause is a certificate and domain mismatch?

Also, one other roadblock is that the folder redirect should be for every folder *except* `/images/` as that's hosted on GitHub already.

Comment: You will need to use a load balancer (or proxy) that supports URL Maps. That also means pointing the domain to the load balancer. If you have a webserver, then why do you want the complexity of mapping URLS to different backends? Either embed the github page within one of your pages, or host the pages on your web server.

Comment: You might be able to put a proxy such as Nginx in front of your web server. I have not tested this with github pages.

Comment: @JohnHanley Hosting the pages myself would be the easiest option but I unfortunately have to keep the static page separate for my solution. I've started looking at reverse proxies in Apache to solve it but it doesn't look pretty.